# Get Index Number of a element in the List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Iam creating a quiz App in flutter , to find  whether the currect answer is selected i want to get the index number of the selected button, i doesnt know whether it is a correct approach to check the correct answer.Please help me how to get the index number when user presses the answer.

```
   {'questionText': "What is your name",
            'answers':['honest','devika','monisha','khyathy'],
          'correctAnswer':'3', 
   },
   {'questionText': "What is your Mobile Name",
   'answers':['Iphone','Huawei','Applele','SAMSUNG'],
   'correctAnswer':'2',
   },
   ];
   void answered(){
     //find the index of the selected answer 
      final result = (questions[questionIndex ]['answers']indexOf());
      if (result== ) { 
        print(result);
      } `
```

Iam calling this List in a raised button in below code:

```
          ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
            return ReusableButton(
              child: Text(answer),
              onPressed:() =>[currentQuestion(),answered()],
              color: Colors.green,
              );
          }).toList(),`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could just make 'correctAnswer' not the index of the answer but the answer itself, so you rather check the two string instead of checking indexes.
It should look like this.

```
{'questionText': "What is your name",
            'answers':['honest','devika','monisha','khyathy'],
          'correctAnswer':'khyathy', 
   },
   {'questionText': "What is your Mobile Name",
   'answers':['Iphone','Huawei','Applele','SAMSUNG'],
   'correctAnswer':'Applele',
   },
   ];
void answered(answer){
      final result = (questions[questionIndex ]['correctAnswer']);
      if (result == answer) { 
        print(result);
      } `
```

I think that's right, it's my first answer in stack overflow so to all the OGs feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thanks it is  working , but the problem is when the answers have so many words it is easy to get errors , so iam looking for index. or is there any option to add A,B,C,D to the question and Call the answer using A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check indexes you could use this.

```
{'questionText': "What is your name",
            'answers':['honest','devika','monisha','khyathy'],
          'correctAnswer':'3', 
   },
   {'questionText': "What is your Mobile Name",
   'answers':['Iphone','Huawei','Applele','SAMSUNG'],
   'correctAnswer':'2',
   },
   ];
void answered(answer){
      final result = (questions[questionIndex ]['correctAnswer']);
      final answerIndex = questions[questionIndex]['answers'].indexOf(answer).toString()
      if (result == answerIndex) { 
        print(result);
      } 
...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
            return ReusableButton(
              child: Text(answer),
              onPressed:() =>[currentQuestion(),answered(answer)],
              color: Colors.green,
              );
          }).toList(),`
```

This should do it, I don't know what your questionIndex function does because you didn't post it so I assumed it returns an int value of the index of the current question.
Also, I don't know if you noticed but in your question, you wrote:

```
      final result = (questions[questionIndex ]['answers']indexOf());
```

indexOf is a list built-in method so when you call it on a list you have to put a dot before it like so:

```
      final result = (questions[questionIndex ]['answers'].indexOf(itemYouWantTheIndex));
```

There is also another error when you check the validity of the answer but I think it is just because you didn't know how to compare.
Tell me if my answer satisfied you, I'd be really happy if it did.

Comment: Thnaks for helping me,

Comment: ```final answerIndex = questions[questionIndex]['answers'].indexOf(answer).toString()```     im getting error on indexof  as undefined method.

Comment: ```questionIndex =0; ``` when button clicked it increment by one . These question are stored as a map in the questions.when  a question index changes we will get next question on screen